# Django haystack. How to alter names of check boxes?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I installed django haystack using whoosh. Everything works great, but I want to alter the names displayed next to the check boxes. I know they are generated using the verbose name set up on the models but I still have an issue with the 's' being added at the end of the names. I know there are custom forms and custom views but I am new to programming and some of the concepts do not make sense. I have also tried to search for any ideas but have had no luck. Any suggestions/advice?

Thanks in advance!
:)

Answer (score 0):

is it not the label=_("Field_name") parameter in the checkbox field?
if its about the verbose name there is also verbose_name_plural which can be set up in models